# (Adobe Animate ActionScript) how can iRemove specific Symballl's from the stage using name, arry, and lib()?

Tags: actionscript, jquery-animate, adobe, removechild, lib

I'm super frustrated with this.

**first for you to understand my code - My goal here is for the user to get randomly selected word appear to them in a way that every letter sits inside of a box.
Then if the user clicks on a button called "Pick a word", another word will be selected and the correct number of boxes will appear.**

I have an array of words like this:

```
   var word_group_1 = ["abolsh", "absorbent", "betrayal", "frutish", "commensurate", "eonfident", "zite"]
```

I'm using this function to select a random word from that array then splice it.. works perfectly:

```
function random_word_genereator() {

random = randomNumber(0, word_group_1.length);

//putting the chosen word from array in the chosen word variable
chosen_word = word_group_1[random]
 //after we used the chosen word were removing it from the away
word_group_1.splice(random, 1)
//splitting the chosen word into an array
chosen_word_letters_arry = chosen_word.split("")
}
```

in a button click  of "pick a word"- I'm creating 5 instances of a Movieclip I have in my library (just a blue box to put text in it) with text in at like this:

```
function create_boxes(e)    
{

//to know which word has been displayed to the user//
old_word=chosen_word
random_word_genereator()    
for (i=0;i<chosen_word.length;i++){

     cell_boxes = new lib.cell_box();   
    stage.addChild(cell_boxes)
    cell_boxes.name="cell_box"+i;
    cell_boxes.x=(xlocation * i) + 50
    cell_boxes.y = 80;
    
    output = new createjs.Text();
    cell_boxes.addChild(output)
        
    output.text=chosen_word_letters_arry[i]
}
```

everything works fine on the first click [As You Can View Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTwbE.png).

The word being selected and displayed on the stage

**my problem is when I'm clicking Again on the button "pick a word"
its not deleting the correct number of boxes.**

I'm putting visible false to the boxes which holds the "Old word" (the one I need to delete)
but [As you can se here After I click again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf6wm.png) its getting messed up.

sometimes its's working, switches from 12 letter word, to a 4 one.
but it should be luck. I'm dying to get this to WORK! its for my school project.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer that will plug and play into your code:

```
js
...

//to know wichh word has been displayed to the user//
old_word=chosen_word
random_word_genereator()    

for (i = 0; i < stage.numChildren; i++) // Loop through all children of the stage
    if (stage.getChildAt(i) is lib.cell_box) // Checks if the child is a lib.cell_box
        stage.removeChildAt(i--); // Removes child from stage and decrements i

for (i=0;i<chosen_word.length;i++){

...
```

Original answer (cleaner code, some restructuring):

It's best to break this kind of logic down into steps.

```
var boxes:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
boxes.y = 80;
addChild(boxes);

...

function createBoxes(word:String):void {
    // Remove boxes first
    while (boxes.numChildren > 0)
        boxes.removeChildAt(0);

    // Add boxes
    for each(var c:String in word.split("")) {
        var box:Box = new Box(c);
        box.x = boxes.width + 50;
        boxes.addChild(box);
    }
}
```

Then set the text inside a Box class.

Comment: first thank you for answering.
i dont know what is class in action script. nither the void you just wrote. 
will it work on actionscript 2? and do you  have a website i cant read about it??

Comment: I assumed you were using AS3. Editing my answer.

Comment: `void` means that a function won't return anything. `doSomething():void` will return nothing but if `doSomething():String` is your return type, you can use it like you would a variable. `var word:String = generateWord();` for example.